# No output after using the Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

```
HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");

String topics = "test4";
HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(" ")));


JavaDStream<String> stream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class,
    StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
    .transformToPair(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, JavaPairRDD<String, String>>() {
      @Override
      public JavaPairRDD<String, String> call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd) {
        rdd.saveAsTextFile("output");
        return rdd;
      }
    }).map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<String, String> kv) {
        return kv._2();
      }
    });
stream1.print();
jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

Cross checked that there is valid data in the topic "test4".

[image]

I am expecting strings that are streamed from the kafka cluster, to be printed in the console.No exceptions in console,but also no output.
Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you called `.start()` and `.awaitTermination()` on the StreamingContext at the end ? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaKafkaWordCount.java#L109

Comment: Yes.Had missed it actually.Called it now. But still no output data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to produce data in your topic **after** the streaming application is started?

By default direct stream use the configuration auto.offset.reset = largest, it means that when there is no initial offset it automatically reset to the largest offset, so basically you will be able to read only the new messages entering in the topic after the streaming application is started.

Comment: Facing the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954252/spark-and-spark-streaming-output-difference-for-the-same-job. I have added ".print",  ".start" & ".awaitTermination" but no output in logs. Same code same file works with Spark. Please check by above SO question

Answer (score 1):

As [ccheneson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143505/ccheneson) says, it could be because you're missing `.start()` and `.awaitTermination()`

Or it could be because [transformations in Spark are lazy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations), which means that you need to add an action to get the results. e.g.

```
stream1.print();
```

Or it could be because the `map` is being performed on the executor(s), so the output would be in the executor's log, rather than the driver's log.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Updating the code with print and start. Yet I'm not able to see any output in the file. Cross-verified that the data is available in the topic.

Comment: Can I have more clarity on your last statement?. I'm running it locally so, will the job not run in the driver itself?

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil Can you please let me know how you solved the issue. Iam also facing the exact same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954252/spark-and-spark-streaming-output-difference-for-the-same-job